# Does this pair of primes $p$ and $q$ exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct odd prime numbers. Does there exist a pair of two distinct odd primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p^q+q^p+1\equiv p+q+1 \pmod{pq-1}$. I have checked $p$ and $q$ with fixed $p=3$ and $7$, but I can't find any solutions. Does this pair $(p,q)$ exist?

Comment: Try $3^7+7^3+1 \equiv (3+7+1) \mod(3\times7-1)$

Comment: Can't see the point of the $+1$ on both sides of the congruence, why not drop it since makes no difference?

Comment: (p,q)=(29,35) also works. Note that $pq-1=0$ (mod xy-1) so that $pq=1$ (mod pq-1). Following coffemath we  can cleanup the equation and multiply with $1=pq$ and manipulate the eaquation (although I didn´t find a solution).

Comment: @MikaelJensen: $35=5\cdot7.$

Comment: @Lucian Sorry! I just noted the relation. Forgot about the prime requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> Here are all solutions from among the first $100$ primes:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

> All solutions with $p\le10^2$ and $q\le10^5$ can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUVRr.png). $($Click on the image to enlarge it$).$

Comment: +1 for this list, which may help someone find a way to get at the solutions. There are so many here, without an apparent pattern, but maybe there is one anyway!

Comment: @coffeemath: If you want to, I could post a link to an extended list, for $p\le10^2$ and $q\le10^5.$